# openxlsx numFmt with period as thousands separator

Tags: r, openxlsx

I am trying to add a new workshet to an excel file with the openxlsx R package. In Denmark we use periods as thousands separators so ideally this is how I would like the output to show in the .xlsx file.

My code looks like this:

```
library(openxlsx)

file <- file.path("S:", "test.xlsx")

df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 200, -3000, 40000, 500000, 6000000),
                 B = c(0.0101, 1.0245, 0.9876, 0.6512, 0.0101, 1.0245))

wb <- loadWorkbook(file)

sht <- addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "newSheet")

head_st <- createStyle(textDecoration = "Bold")
number_st <- createStyle(numFmt = "#.##0")
pct_st <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE")

writeData(wb, sht, df, headerStyle = head_st)

addStyle(wb, sht, style = number_st, 
         cols=c(1), rows = 2:(nrow(df) + 1), gridExpand = TRUE)
addStyle(wb, sht, style = pct_st, 
         cols=c(2), rows = 2:(nrow(df) + 1), gridExpand = TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb, file, overwrite = TRUE)
```

The excel output is shown below.

[image]

The percentages come out exactly how they are supposed to (with comma as decimal separator).
However, the number format is not right!

I tried to solve it several ways, by going into the number formatting in excel and try to see how they define it:

[image: solution2]

Where I have also tried `"#.##0;-#.##0"` as well as the longer one in the below picture:

[image: solution2]

But that gives an error which I am not sure how to solve or if it helps with my issue.

```
> number_st <- createStyle(numFmt = "_-* #.##0_-;-* #.##0_-;_-* "-"??_-;_-@_-")
Error in "_-* #.##0_-;-* #.##0_-;_-* " - "??_-;_-@_-" : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `scales` package and format it in R before writing out to excel. I don't think you'd be able to perform number functions in excel after this since the number is being formatted as text.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 200, -3000, 40000, 500000, 6000000),
                 B = c(0.0101, 1.0245, 0.9876, 0.6512, 0.0101, 1.0245))

new_percent <- number_format(decimal.mark = ",", suffix = "%", accuracy = .01, scale = 100, big.mark = ",")

new_decimal <- number_format(big.mark = ".")

df <- df %>% 
    mutate(A_new = new_decimal(A)) %>% 
    mutate(B_new = new_percent(B))


wb <- createWorkbook()

sht <- addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "newSheet")


head_st <- createStyle(textDecoration = "Bold")

writeData(wb, sht, df, headerStyle = head_st)



openXL(wb)
```

[image]